# Unable to find the processes that uses a certain port on Windows 10

Tags: windows, port, netstat

unforuneatelly  I am not able to start any process on port 2022 on my computer. I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 1803. I tried to start an IIS site on that port and got an "HRESULT: 0x80070020" error. The same happens when I start an angular "ng serve" on that port.

I tried to find out what process is using that port via `netstat -ano | find ":2022"` but that gave no output at all (works for other ports). The Windows Resource Manager does not show that port eigther.

Sometimes if I'm lucky after re-adding the site to IIS and reboot the IIS can start on that port.

Answer (score 0):

You should not simply filter on port number, like 2022: "netstat" sometimes returns ranges or wildcards, check the entire "netstat" result if any range or wildcard might cover your 2022 port.

Comment: Nothing in the result as well. Are -ano the correct parameters?